# Downgrading Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300 Downgrade Confusion

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.1-jelly-bean, 4.3-jelly-bean, rom, downgrade

My **Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300** is currently running Android version 4.3.0. I wanted to downgrade it back to 4.1.2 and got confused with which values to look for when selecting a rom. I know that my carrier is TEN (Telenor) Norway and that my PDA is I9300XXUGNG3. Looking up that combination I managed to verify that my carrier is indeed Telenor. Based on that, can I pick any 4.1.2 firmware that is associated with my carrier?

Answer (score 0):

If the phone is unlocked, then go ahead.
It wouldn't matter which carrier that firmware belongs to. As long as it's stock, then you can flash it with no worries.